# Sybse ASE Configuration for Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, sap-ase

I am very new to Fluent NHibernate.

Is there any configuration available for Sybase Ase?
If not, how would I create one?
Could you please point me to the right resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about this particular Hibernate variation, but for Hibernate in general, see:
•          https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateSybaseIntegration
•          http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20155.1570/html/OS_SDK_nf/OS_SDK_nf76.htm